# Can't use conda environment in VSCode

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Today I can't use my env in Visual Studio Code. I've tried to restart my computer, reinstall Jupyter extensions in VSCode but nothing works. Here are some pictures of the "errors":

1. Here it can't even print 1
   [image: error1]
2. Main error
   [image: error2]

This message shows up and never ends

I've tried using other envs and they seem to be fine and working. What's' the problem with this env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was giving me this error due to not updating `tensorflow` to version `2.8`. The issue here is that I was succesfully using this env for the past 6 months without any problem, so I don't know why now sstarted failing...

Comment: Do you mean after updating `tensorflow` all the errors are gone?

Comment: @Shayan yes! I had `tensorflow==2.3`. This wasn't giving me errors until yesterday, but when I updated it (and `tensorflow-text`) the issue disappeared.